# iOS Universal Links apple-app-site-association File Mix 2 Signatures For Same App

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have an app on the app store that use `UniversalLinks` I want to be able to test the functionality in development also.
Is it possible to have the `apple-app-site-association` file like so with both signatures?

```
{
"applinks": {
"apps": [ ],
"details": [
  {
    "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.EP.myCompany.client",
    "paths": [
      "*", "/"
    ]
  },
  {
    "appID": "XXXXXXXXXX.com.myCompany.client",
    "paths": [
      "*", "/"
    ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Check out examples from others to see how AASA is formatted. Like https://facebook.com/apple-app-site-association or https://amazon.com/apple-app-site-association

Comment: Thank you for sharing that!